# Emacs frustration with web development any working dot-files?

Tags: php, html, emacs, editor

I really liked flexibility of emacs but it is really annoying to make it work. I want to use it for web development html, css, javascript, php. I first tried [emacs-starter-kit](http://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit) . It didn't included [nXhtml](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html). Also C-g key binding does not work (they call it starter kit but basic key command does not work). I think it is mapped for git control. That's a frustration for a beginner. Then I replaced emacs-starter-kit with nXhtml. At least C-g is working. But code completion sucks, M-tab does not work. I tried code completion from nXhtml menu  with no success. Also NXhtml mode did'nt colorized my file if css is mixed with html. Isn't it recommended for mixed html, css,php files. So why it doesnt work?. Why Emacs folks do not aware of convention over configuration? Dam! ship it something works! Please help me before I am getting crazy. I use Ubuntu 10.04 and emacs-snaphot-gtk 23.1.50-1. Please guide me step by step with your working dotfile url. Even I accept I am a dummy, it is really annoying and frustrating to use emacs.

Comment: Ditch the starter kit and stick with the normal Emacs. Also, my advice is, don't install anything called "snapshot" - use the stable version.

Comment: This isn't really the best place to vent frustration. If you have an actual problem then ask a question but all the loaded "Why Emacs folks do not aware of convention over configuration?" type statements are not required. Also, this is probably a better question for superuser.com anyway.

Comment: I will but M-tab (code completion) does not work.

Comment: Sounds like the emacs-starter-kit is just another junk program to be avoided.

Comment: codeka:you are right it might be better for superuser. But convention overconfiguration really helps newbies. Any pro can customize his own dot-files. But give a chance for newbies with a working dotfiles that  gives features similar to modern IDEs.

Comment: I'm not part of the Vim > Emacs parade, they are equally as good as each other. But, for my personal preference, I use Vim. Have you given it a go? I'm not saying it'll do everything you want, cause it might not. But its as easy as 'apt-get install gvim' to test it out.

Comment: Thanks Christian if I can't make it up with emacs I will try vim as a next solution.

Comment: I'm doing web development (Ruby on Rails, html/css/php/js) and using this http://github.com/spastorino/my_emacs_for_rails. Maybe can give u the idea of how to do things?

Comment: I understand your frustration. It took me over 3 full days to be able to install and get emacs + auctex + preview-latex to work. I spent a the day yesterday trying to configure Emacs to send/receive email using my gmail account and nothing. No website gives the full information and most places assume too much knowledge. It is really frustrating. I thought I was OK with computers, but three weeks with Emacs and I feel like a dummy, too. The more I go on, though, the more I am fascinated with the power and flexibility of Emacs. I think and hope my effort and time will pay off.

Comment: I disagree that there should be "working dotfiles" for newbies. Emacs is working just fine out of the box, and hence if you want working .emacs file, just put nothing there! I personally never copied others' dotfile word by word - I only take the lines I need.

Comment: @polygot, I started using vim with somebody elses dotfiles and its the only way I was willing to give it a go. Fair enough, I could have just put up with it and created my own, but sometimes you need just that little bit of extra help to make it more attractive to learn. I know it works out of the box fine, but that little bit of extra familiarity can go a long way to seeing it through.

Comment: as a tech writer who uses emacs regularly, RTFM! it's all in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html) if you haven't already.  You are running Emacs under X.  In that case, you should try if Esc-Tab works for code completion.  M-Tab might be lost to the X for switching between processes.

Programs like Emacs and Vim demand that you invest time and effort before they start paying off.  They pay off really good in terms if not getting in the way of real work.  I suggest you to find time to get acquainted with such programs before venting out.

Comment: Esc-Tab did not worked. But from Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts-Window Management-> Move between Windows, using a popup window  - I changed it to Windows+Tab and it worked.